Copying several folders from remote to local via bash script, only authenticating once
First things first: I am fairly new to bash scripting, so forgive me any crucial oversights.
On a remote machine, I have the following folder structure:
base_path/

batch1

model1

folder_a

folder_b

...



model2

...



batch2
...

Whenever a batch is finished, I want to copy some folders to my local machine. Within each model folder, there are many subfolders (folder_a, folder_b, etc...). To reduce the workload and time needed for file transfer, I only want to copy some folders (lets say folder_a and folder_b) of every model of the batch in question to local. However, as the remote machine requires two-factor authentication, I am prompted with a authentication request for every scp command that I initiate on local. I can not create ssh keys as one part of the 2 factor authentication of the remote machine changes every few seconds.
I am looking for a solution, where I specify the batch name when executing a shell script that copies folder_a and folder_b of every model in said batch to local. As folder_a and folder_b have identical names, I need to preserve the folder structure of the remote machine. Furthermore, I need to set it up in a way that I am not prompted with an authentication request for every scp command.
My last attempt included a cat <<EOF approach, where I tried to scram all commands that I wanted to execute remotely into a variable and then executing it via one ssh command (I redacted USER and HOST information). Furthermore I need to make directories on local according to the file structure on remote which I only know as soon as I am on the remote machine.
#!/bin/bash

# Remote server details
REMOTE_USER="USER"
REMOTE_HOST="HOST"
REMOTE_DIRECTORY="/smth/smth/smth/$1"
REMOTE_FOLDERS=("folder_a" "folder_b")
LOCAL_USERNAME=$(whoami)
LOCAL_IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
LOCAL_DIRECTORY="$PWD/$1"
mkdir -p "$LOCAL_DIRECTORY"

remote_commands=$(cat <<EOF
cd "$REMOTE_DIRECTORY"
folders=\$(ls -d */)
for folder in \$folders; do
    for remote_folder in \${REMOTE_FOLDERS[@]}; do
        echo "\$folder/\$remote_folder"
        scp -r "\$folder/\$remote_folder" "$LOCAL_USERNAME@$LOCAL_IP:$LOCAL_DIRECTORY/\$folder"
    done
done
EOF
)

# Start an SSH session and run commands, capturing the output
output=$(ssh -T "$REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST" "$remote_commands" 2>/dev/null)

# Display the output
echo "$output"


You define REMOTE_FOLDERS in local and expand it in remote, not sure if there are other problems.

Did you look at rsync? This might be what you need. It can copy anything in one single run, can include/exclude directories at will... Try man rsync.

Use public key authentication rather than passwords, then you won't have to authenticate manually.

tmpl=/tmp/sshctl/'%L-%r@%h:%p'; ssh -nNf -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath="$tmpl" user@host / scp -o ControlPath="$tmpl" ... / ssh -O exit -o ControlPath="$tmpl" user@host

@Barmar see end of paragraph 3

can also use ControlMaster technique with rsync -e
